# Where should we load libraries .so in android so that there would be not any memory leakage on unloading?

Tags: android, memory, service, java-native-interface

I have to use a jni libraries in my project. Should I load that library in Service or in a separate thread or using Service as a separate process. When i tried to launch it in a thread and then cleaning the resources and when again reloading and using it, it was crashing. May be it would be memory leak. What is best way of loading and unloading the library? I saw somewhere that those libraries can not be unloaded. It will be done by GC only.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, JNI shared libraries should not be unloaded. Actually, Java classes can not be unloaded, too. This is not a memory leak, and has little to do with Garbage Collector.

Unless you have some very special setup, it is recommended to put `System.load()` in the static constructor of the class (or classes) that use this native library. Whether your service runs in-process or in a separate process, the framework will handle this for you.

If you do some sensitive work in `JNI_OnLoad()` of your library, you may take special care of not doing this work twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to do clean up. So should I delete allocated memory using some native function. and then next time if again i want to use those libraries, then instantiate it? Till classes would be loaded, libraries would also be loaded. What will happen to native libraries when classes are garbage collected?

Comment: On Android, classes are never garbage collected, and cannot be unloaded. But wait, there is another problem: Android framework will most likely kill your process when it needs memory, without even letting you perform any cleanup. The only method that is guaranteed to be called for your Activity, is `onPause()`. And if you dare spend too many milliseconds in this method, your app will be killed no matter what.